# How do i mount Stripe's Payment Element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

Hello i am trying to mount Stripe's input fields to accept a credit/debit card. I know that i should use the payment element as the say on documentation. I am using node.js with Ionic 5 Angular 15 capacitor 5. As per to HTML i use

```
 <form id="payment-form" (ngSubmit)="subscribe()">
    <div id="payment-element">
      <!-- Elements will create form elements here -->
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Subscribe</button>
    <div id="error-message">
      <!-- Display error message to your customers here -->
    </div>
  </form>
```

and my component.ts is this UPDATED CODE

```
    import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserData } from 'src/app/services/user-data/user-data';
import { loadStripe, Stripe, StripeElements, StripeCardElement, StripeElementsOptions, } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-subscription',
  templateUrl: 'subscription.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['subscription.page.scss'],
})
export class SubscriptionPage {
  stripe: Stripe;
  elements: StripeElements;
  paymentElement: StripeCardElement;
  clientSecret: string = ''; // You need to set this to your actual client secret
  appearance: any = { /* appearance */ };

  user: any = {};
  email: string = '';
  uid: string = '';

  cardDetail: any = {
    name: '',
    cardNumber: '',
    expiryDate: '',
    securityCode: '',
  };

  menuOpenCopyright: boolean = false;

  modalOpen: boolean = false;
  cardInputFocused: boolean = false;

  constructor(public router: Router, public userData: UserData) {
    this.user = this.userData.getUserData();
    this.uid = this.user.uid;
    this.email = this.user.email;
  }

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Initialize Stripe with your publishable key
    this.initializeStripe();
  }


  async initializeStripe() {
    try {
      // Load Stripe.js
      const stripePromise = loadStripe('your_publishable_key'); // Replace with your actual publishable key
      const stripe = await stripePromise;

      // Set up Stripe.js and Elements
      const elements = stripe.elements();
      const paymentElement = elements.create('card');
      paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');

      // Set the payment element to the class property
      this.paymentElement = paymentElement;
      this.stripe = stripe;
      this.elements = elements;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error initializing Stripe:', error);
    }
  }
  
  

  async subscribe() {
    try {
     event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Card Number: ' + this.cardDetail.cardNumber);

    // Destroy the existing card element if it exists
    if (this.paymentElement) {
      this.paymentElement.destroy();
    }

    this.elements = this.stripe.elements({ appearance: this.appearance });

    // Create a new payment element
    this.paymentElement = this.elements.create('card');

    // Mount the card element to the 'payment-element' container
    this.paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');

      // Tokenize the card details using the new cardElement
      const { token, error } = await this.stripe.createToken(this.paymentElement, {
        name: this.cardDetail.name,
        address_line1: '', // Include any relevant address information here
        address_city: '', // Include city information here
        address_state: '', // Include state information here
        address_zip: '', // Include ZIP code here
        address_country: '', // Include country information here
      });

      if (!error) {
        console.log('Tokenization successful');

        const paymentData = {
          email: this.cardDetail.email,
          token: token.id,
          uid: this.uid,
          name: this.cardDetail.name,
          business: this.cardDetail.business,
        };
  
        // Send the token and user's email to your server
        this.userData.createCustomer(paymentData).subscribe((customerResponse: any) => {
          if (customerResponse.success) {
            const customerId = customerResponse.customer.id;
            console.log('Customer created:', customerResponse.customer);
            this.userData.createSetupIntent(customerId).subscribe((setupIntentResponse: any) => {
              if (setupIntentResponse.success) {
                const setupIntentClientSecret = setupIntentResponse.setupIntent.client_secret;
  
                // Create a subscription with the saved payment method
                const planId = 'price_1O2VVjGozbMWFnurNiXUurH7'; // Replace with your actual pricing plan ID
                this.userData.createSubscription(customerId, planId).subscribe((subscriptionResponse: any) => {
                  if (subscriptionResponse.success) {
                    console.log('Subscription successful:', subscriptionResponse.subscription);
                  } else {
                    console.error(subscriptionResponse.error);
                  }
                });
              } else {
                console.error(setupIntentResponse.error);
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.error(customerResponse.error);
            console.error('Error creating customer:', customerResponse.error);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.error('Tokenization error:', error);
        // Handle the error if tokenization fails
        console.error(error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in subscribe:', error);
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

the createCustomer, createSetupIntent are working fine i can show the input fields to put card number, CVC and expiration date but it is not style do i need to do something about appearance?

Answer (score 0):

Your `options` object has the wrong value for the `clientSecret`.  You're passing in your secret API key, which should *never* be shared with the client.  That key can be used to perform just about any operation on your account, and should be treated like a sensitive password.

Instead, [you need to pass the client secret of the Setup Intent or Payment Intent there](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create#stripe_elements-options-clientSecret).

I *think* that's the primary issue, but it's hard to say because you didn't share your Console output.  If passing in the correct client secret value doesn't work please update your question with the full Console logs when you try to load the page.

Comment: thanks Justin for the response. I got that but my problem is with the appearance i think. Now i am getting card number, MM/YY as i shown on the image. Do i need to style?

Comment: I don't see an image in your question or comment, can you take a screenshot of what you're seeing, add it to your question, and clarify what you're asking about?